# netflix conductor - http type task - should not start with workflow - to achieve retry

Tags: http, netflix, retry-logic, netflix-conductor

I have created a task with retry of 5 times.And created a workflow using the task of http type(my rest url api endpoint) for input parameters.

But the moment I run the workflow - it is hitting the rest api.
where actually I want to run the task by worker - inside my rest service to call another upstream service.

what I want - the rest url(url-2) is the Upstream of another url(url-1). when my application call url-1, in code I will use conductor task to hit url-2, and based on status, or down, I will fail the status- and it will retry.

Comment: i don't fully understand this "But the moment I run the workflow - it is hitting the rest api. where actually I want to run the task by worker " if you put an http task it will hit the api. Do you mean you want a custom-worker aka Simple task?